# Why are the onCreate methods of Android Views not just the constructors?

Tags: java, android, android-view

Android's `onCreate` methods seems to do all the things you would normally do in a constructor.

I have some code which programatically adds some views to a layout, and having an `onCreate` methods seems a little pointless - I only do it for consistency.

```
    for (Contact contact : manager.getContacts()) {
        GuiContact guiContact = new GuiContact(contact, this);
        guiContact.onCreate();

        // add them to the UI
        guiContact.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ));
        contactListLayout.addView(guiContact);
    }
```

Why is this functionality in `onCreate` rather than in the constructors?

(There would be advantages relating to `final` members, if the functionality was in the constructors.)

Comment: The context nor the layout is available at the point of the constructor. On a related note, you can also do variable initialization inside of `onStart`. In other words, `onCreate` has a purpose for being the way it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you never instantiate an `Activity` yourself. The system does it for you. And in order to do so, it needs a constructor without any parameters. So, it is better to do the initialization in `onCreate()`.

Also, you set your `Activity`s layout in the `onCreate()` method, so getting a handle to that layout in the constructor will not work, and you will not be able to dynamically add views into it.

Comment: Also because as you said, an activity never get destroyed, but need to "re-create" whenever it comes back from background, so it needs a method to do the initial work

Comment: he is asking abour `guiContact.onCreate()` so what `Activity` do you see here? `guiContact` is a `View` instance since `setLayoutParams` is called on it and also it is passed to `ViewGroup#addView` method